# httplistener for URLs except localhost

Tags: c#, httplistener

i'm trying to listen to clients requests using httplister in c# but it works only for http://localhost/
how can I listen to http://www.anywebsite.com/

i'm using the follwing code

```
var web = new HttpListener();

    web.Prefixes.Add("http://www.dfdfdfdfdfd.com/");

    Console.WriteLine("Listeningg..");

    web.Start();

    Console.WriteLine(web.GetContext());

    var context = web.GetContext();

    var response = context.Response;

    const string responseString = "<html><body>Hello world</body></html>";

    var buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseString);

    response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;

    var output = response.OutputStream;

    output.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

    Console.WriteLine(output);

    output.Close();

    web.Stop();

    Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Where are you planning on running this script from? On some other server's local machine?

Comment: I Tried on the same computer and  on differnt two computers on the same local network
@nocturns2

Answer (score 1):

I've tested your code on my computer and it has worked.
To try i've modified my C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file and i added the line

```
127.0.0.1   www.dfdfdfdfdfd.com
```

Then i've opened a new command prompt and tested with

```
ping www.dfdfdfdfdfd.com
```

`I've tested with edge browser with success

Comment: it works thank you...I wonder if there is a way to put all URLs in one line
like " * " or somthing like this

Comment: what about the hosts file?What should I add there?

Comment: with this prefixes you can get all request made to your httplistener class, in hosts file you can add the item that you need: www.12345.com, www.abcdef.com, www.whatyouneed.com or something else...

Comment: I really appreciate your help but i tried **Prefixes.Add("http://*/");** and nothing happened
it only worked when I add("mywebsite"); to perfixes in code and in hosts file
is there a way to put all sites in one line in hosts file?for both http and https ?